# What does this Shunting-Yard algorithm statement mean?

Tags: java, arguments, shunting-yard

I am trying to develop a Shunting-Yard Algorithm based on pseudocode from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

One of the operations states:

> If the token is a function argument separator (e.g., a comma) [...]

Could someone please clarify what this means?

Comment: Exactly what's unclear about that?

Answer (score 2):

It's simply referring to however the language specifies separations between the arguments of a function.

For example, in Java:

`public void foo(int a, int b) { ... }`

The function arguments `a` and `b` are separated using a comma.

Comment: Hi,Thanks very much for the quick reply :) In terms of the shunting-yard algorithm code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail                                  What does this mean Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a function that takes 3 parameters or arguments:

```
someFunction(int i, String s, boolean b) {}
```

Each one of those parameters is separated by a comma. This is how it is done in java and many other languages but perhaps there are other separators used in some languages as well.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi,Thanks very much for the quick reply :) In terms of the shunting-yard algorithm code here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/… What does this mean Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know how to put it into any other words. It really is self explanatory. Each parameter to a function is separated by something (a comma, etc...) and the algorithm wants you to find those things. This will allow you to find how many parameters have been passed in.